# How to delete file that cannot be deleted on a NTFS partition

Tags: release-freya, dual-boot, ntfs

I have 2 files on my NTFS partition. One of them is 666 bytes and the other is 0 bytes. When trying to delete them it says that it does not exist

I have tried the `rm` command from the terminal and it does not work

Comment: How are the files called?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Do you mean the file name

Comment: Yes, precisely. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto It is **IE11 - Win8.1.ova**. I tried deleting with `sudo rm "./IE11 - Win8.1.ova"` but it doesn't work

Comment: I am not sure about that `./` inside the quotes. You tried also without those two characters, right?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yes I did try without those 2 characters

Comment: Did you try running `fsck` on the file system?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I think it might be better to run check disk from Windows 10 since I haven't ever used `fsck` on an NTFS and historically Linux has been corrupting NTFS partitions (doesn't do it anymore but I don't know about ```fsck```)

Comment: You didn't mention you had Windows as well. If you do, of course go for `chkdsk`. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I try running ```chkdsk``` on Windows 10 tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

What if you try to delete them from Files? What happens?

I had the same problem in the past, it was related to encoding of file names.

There is a program `ntfsfix` that can fix some ntfs problems:

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sd(your partition here)
```

According to the man pages:

ntfsfix is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.  ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some fundamental NTFS inconsistencies, resets the NTFS journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

You may run `ntfsfix` on an NTFS volume if you think it was damaged by Windows or some other way and it cannot be mounted.

---

Also there is this interesting link, could be helpful:

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/delete-remove-files-with-inode-number.html

Another interesting link:

https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/can-two-files-have-the-same-inode-number-423094/

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried [Be careful with sudo and rm... great power great responsibility]:

```
sudo su
rm "[full path of the file]"
```

Comment: It says no such file or directory